# Updated my Joomla backend to 3.8 from 3.4 mistakenly, now I cannot access back end

Tags: joomla

I updated my Joomla backend to 3.8 from 3.4 mistakenly, now I cannot access back end but can access cPanel front end, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: contact to server hosting company to revert last day files ...its can be done last 24hrs files to reset your website

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that one or more third party plugins or other extensions installed on your website are not Joomla 3.8 compatible yet.

I recommend the following:

1. Edit your `configuration.php` file via cPanel File Manager or similar and set $error_reporting = 'development'
2. browse the back-end of your website to check for any error messages that may give you a clue about which extensions are causing the error
3. temporarily disable the extension(s) that are causing the error(s) by using File Manager in cPanel or similar to rename the `filename.php` file to `filename.php.old` or similar
4. assuming you can now log in to the back-end, update third party extensions to the latest versions and set $error_reporting = 'none' in Global Configuration